Intersection of a $C^\infty$ manifold and a sufficiently small ball
Let $K\subset \mathcal{R}^n$ be a compact  and convex set with non-empty interior and suppose its boundary $\partial K$ is a $C^\infty$ manifold. Let $y\in \partial K$.

I want to argue there exists a $\delta>0$ such that $\forall 0<\delta'<\delta$, both $B_{\delta'}(y)\cap K$ and $B_{\delta'}\setminus K$ are connected. If this statement is true, any reference or hints on how to prove it would be greatly appreciated. If this is not true, please provide a counter example.
In 2D if $K$ is a circle, I can see this is true for any $\delta$. What other types of $\partial K$, would it work if I make the $\delta$ small enough? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My attempt: Based on @Makhil Katz's answer, I revised my attempt as follows.

By Theorem 3.1 and Lemma 3.3 of his paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1910.02432 , there exists a $\delta>0$ such that $\forall 0<\delta'<\delta$, for which both $B_{\delta'}(y)\cap K$ and $B_{\delta'}(y)\setminus K$ have connected boundaries.
Both sets are subsets of a connected space, namely $B_{\delta'}(y)$.
If a set $A$ is a subset of a connected space, and if $A$ has a connected boundary, $cl(A)$ is connected. (Showing that if the boundary of a set is connected, then the closure is connected.).
Therefore, the closure of my two sets of interest are connected.
I don't quite get what I want though: because just because the closure of a set is connected, the interior is not necessarily connected. But at least, does the argument above work to show the closures of these sets are connected sets? Did I apply Katz's theorem correctly?


This is certainly false as stated. $K$ can have non-empty interior but yet part of its boundary can separate $\Bbb R^n$. For example, take $K$ to be the union of a ball and a sphere, and take $y$ in the sphere.

@Ted Shifrin Do you think it would help if I assume $K$ is also connected? Perhaps even convex?

You can have very pathological compact subsets. Assuming $K$ is convex or at least the closure of a connected open set may be reasonable.

@TedShifrin I have updated the question with the additional assumption of $K$ being convex.

So now I'm going to suggest that you look at the Jordan-Brouwer Separation Theorem (for example, in Guillemin and Pollack). Something much stronger than what you want holds for a smooth compact hypersurface of $\Bbb R^n$.

@TedShifrin Thank you so much. In that case, I can relax my assumption of $K$ to be the closure of bounded open set with $C^\infty$ boundary? I don't need the convexity?

If the boundary is connected, that’ll be fine. But I’m worried that craziness may occur if the boundary has lots of components.

@TedShifrin I think I need more hint. I looked up the Jordan theorem but it only says the hypersurface separates its complement into two connected components. From this how can I make my argument about separating my ball, $B_{\delta'}(y)$ into two connected components?

Oh, I lost track. You do need convexity to get $B_\delta(y)\backslash K$ to be connected.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@TedShifrin I can show $B_{\delta'}(y)\cap K$ is connected. IT is the intersection of two convex sets so it is convex and therefore, connected. I am stumped on how to show $B_{\delta'}(y)\setminus K$ is connected even with the convexity assumption.

I would write $\partial K$ as the graph of a concave function over the tangent plane and show the part of the ball lying above it is path connected.

@TedShifrin If I assume convexity, do I still need the smoothness of the boundary $\partial K$?

This was proved in

Katz, Mikhail G.
Convexity, critical points, and connectivity radius.
Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 148 (2020), no. 3, 1279–1281

using the ideas around critical points following Grove, Shiohama, Gromov, and Cheeger.

Thank you so much. I will study your paper. Which Theorems or Lemmas should I focus on?

The first three pages.
